# A 401 error when Using Axios to get data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hello I have a problem That I don't know how to solve, I am using an API to get the list of movies, my URLs are set right, I verified them multiple times

Here is my ReactJS code to use :

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`${API_END_POINT}${POPULAR_MOVIES_URL}&${POPULAR_MOVIES_URL}`);
   }

// my render method here thet return a simple element

}
```

But I get this error on my console :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

Is there a solution for this ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 401 means 'Unauthorized error' so you need some login credentials along with the request. What specific API are you trying to reach?

Comment: api Movie DB ( https://www.themoviedb.org/  )

Comment: here are my URLs used :

Comment: const API_END_POINT = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
const API_KEY = "66051677517eb0d913a8f93b8559fc31";
const POPULAR_MOVIES_URL =
  "discover/movie?language=fr&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&append_to_response=images";
const API_KEY_URL = "api_key=[66051677517eb0d913a8f93b8559fc31]";

Comment: You need to be sure that what you're sending is exactly what the API asks for

Comment: I cannot see you using the api_key in your request. This guide https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/authentication tells you a correct url. you need to use api_key as a query parameter in your request.

Comment: George : Well I corrected that I still get the same error : 
axios
      .get(`${API_END_POINT}${POPULAR_MOVIES_URL}&${API_KEY_URL}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });

Comment: I corrected my error, Thanks to you all.